# Anonymous View.OnDragListener in custom ListViewAdapter results in NoClassDefFound exception?

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I am trying to set a View.OnDragListener in my custom ListViewAdapter.getView() method, but every time I do so, I get this exception

> E/AndroidRuntime(2472): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CustomListAdapter$3

Why does this happen? I have no problem with setting an OnClickListener?

My code

```
public class CustomListAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

...

@Override
public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

...

    convertView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag (View v, DragEvent event)
        {
            Log.d("TEST", "Drag: " + event);
            return true;
        }
    });
...


}

...

}
```

Comment: Are you using an inner class inside of CustomListAdapter?

Comment: No - I am just using an anonymous method. I updated my post with a code snippet

Comment: do you import the right class (android.view.View.OnDragListener)? are you sure you run it on a api 11+ device?

Comment: Hmm, it seems my device is not new enough, since it's only API level 8. I though it would support setOnDragListener? Is there something else I can use on API level 8?